# (Some) programs wont start at boot unless I login first

Tags: ssh, boot

I have a Debian server that I upgraded to version 10, and since then a few programs I have wont boot unless I login first (locally, via Digital Ocean console).

Scenario is this:

1. I reboot the server.
2. I try to login to the server via ssh, but it wont connect.
3. I login to the server (as root) locally via Digital Ocean console.
4. I can now login to the server via ssh.

Why doesn't ssh (and nginx) start without me needing to login the server first?

Comment: The services do not start at all or they do not have access to some files (stored in your home directory)?

Comment: They start automatically when I login as root.